# Layout problem with sticky elements and media queries

Tags: html, css

> First of all, I'm sorry for my terrible title, please rename this question if you think of a better title.

I would like to display adapt the layout of my page on mobile. The current desktop version is:

[image: Desktop]

And I'd like to do something like:

[image: Mobile]

The text is sticky and adapts itself via JS while scrolling through each step. So, I have a `.text-container` element that has a specific height matching the entire height of the drawings. And my `.text` element is the element that is `sticky`.

So my HTML looks like:

```html
<article>
    <div class="figure">
        <div class="step" id="step-1"></div>
        <div class="step" id="step-2"></div>
        <div class="step" id="step-2-5"></div>
        <div class="step" id="step-3"></div>
        <div class="step" id="step-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-container">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>
                Step <span>1</span>
            </h1>
            <div class="bold">Alice’s phone broadcasts a random message every few minutes</div>
            <p>
                In order to maintain user privacy, the message is sent over Bluetooth and does not use location for proximity detection.
                <br>
                This message is called a Proximity Identifier or EphID. Theses identifiers are unique and change often.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

And here's the CSS I'm applying to adapt the layout (the code here is in SCSS):

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    article {
        .text-container {
            .text {
                top: 50vh;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 50vh;
                background: grey;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this:

[image: Bug]

It seems that something is wrong with the width and the positioning of the `.text` element.

> As requested in the comments, here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/arguiot/pen/oNjxjeV), without the images but it works the same)

Comment: create a fiddle for your code.

Comment: @AwaisNawaz I've updated the question with a link to a CodePen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just realized my question was a bit stupid. I had a `max-width` property that was messing with the layout.

I'm posting the code I changed, just in case someone has the same problem as me:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    article {
        .text-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100vh;
            left: 0;
            .text {
                position: -webkit-sticky;
                position: sticky;
                top: 50vh;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                max-width: 100vw;
                height: 50vh;
                background: grey;
            }
        }
    }
}
```